# Alternative way to view MathJax in titles

Tags: feature-request, android-app, mathjax

I've searched and found that MathJax will probably never be rendered in titles on the Android app. However, recently a mechanism has been added to render MathJax in comments, not in real time but on request. Would it be possible to get something like this for titles?